# How to display two complete images in the same div size, like behance?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, tailwind-css

**First of all, sorry for my bad english**

It turns out that I am trying to make a section where several images are shown, the format is that the user previously loads the **images** and the number of **columns** per **block/div** from a form.

Now my problem is when the images within the same **block/div** are of different sizes, I don't know if it is because of different height or width.

What I managed to do is make them both have the same size, all inside the **block/div**, but they lose the content, that is, they don't look complete.

Now I pass two screenshots, where the **first** is how it fits me, and the **second** is how I would like it, which would be a style to **behance with the grids**. Because of my bad English

[my case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkIjm.jpg)

[behance case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxPwR.jpg)

Now I pass you part of the code that I am implementing!

```
<section id="content-body" class=" " style="">
    
    <input id="{{project.id}}" type="text" class="pid" style="display:none;">

    <div  class=" mt-20 mb-10 grid place-items-center" style="">

        {% for data in projectImages %}

        <div x-data="{dropdownOpen: false}" @click.outside="dropdownOpen = false"  class="relative group/cuadricula">

            <div class="grid max-w-7xl mb-3 gap-3" style=" grid-template-columns: repeat({{data.columns}}, minmax(0, 1fr)); ">
                
                {% for img in data.images.all %}
                <div class="overflow-hidden " style=" display:flex;">
                    <img id="{{img.id}}" class="object-cover w-full transition duration-300 ease-in-out hover:scale-110 click-open-modalZoomImagen" src="{{img.image.url}}" alt=""  style=""/>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
                
            </div>

        <!-- BOTON EDITAR CUADRICULA -->
            <div @click="dropdownOpen = !dropdownOpen" class="z-10 absolute top-1 left-1   group/edit ">
                    <button :class="dropdownOpen ? 'visible' : 'invisible group-hover/cuadricula:visible' "  class="btn-editProjectImages bg-black border-0 p-4 rounded text-white hover:text-blue-700 transition ">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 ">
                            <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M16.862 4.487l1.687-1.688a1.875 1.875 0 112.652 2.652L6.832 19.82a4.5 4.5 0 01-1.897 1.13l-2.685.8.8-2.685a4.5 4.5 0 011.13-1.897L16.863 4.487zm0 0L19.5 7.125" />
                        </svg>  
                    </button>
                    <div :class="dropdownOpen ? 'top-full opacity-100 visible' : 'invisible opacity-0' " class="border-light shadow-card absolute left-0 z-10 mt-2  rounded border-0 bg-black text-white py-1 transition-all ">
                        <a href="{% url 'project-images-edit' p_pk=project.pk pk=data.pk %}" class="text-body-color hover:bg-primary hover:text-primary block py-2 px-5 text-base font-semibold hover:bg-opacity-5 w-full hover:text-blue-700">
                        Edit
                        </a>
                        <a href="{% url 'project-images-delete' p_pk=project.pk pk=data.pk %}" class="text-body-color hover:bg-primary hover:text-primary block py-2 px-5 text-base font-semibold hover:bg-opacity-5 w-full hover:text-blue-700">
                            Delete
                        </a>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}  

    </div>
</section>
```

And here is a part of the style sheet

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


#main-content{ min-height: 100vh; margin:0; }

#navbar{ min-height:50px; z-index: 1;}

#main-content{ display:flex; flex-direction:column; }
#content-body{ flex:1; }

#footer{ min-height:50px;}
```

From already thank you very much! I hope you can understand and help me. Anything if you need more details, I'll pass it on! If they do it only with CSS without tailwind, there is no problem!

---

**Update**

I am going to pass an html and css code with what I am trying to later adapt it to the main.
I will also post a photo of how it looks and another photo of how I would like it to look

[my case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFxvo.jpg)

[behance case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjXeQ.jpg)

and now the code

```html
<section id="navbar"></section>
    <section id="main-content">
        <div class="padre">
            <div class="contenedor-imagenes">
                <img src="../media/3.jpg"/ class="imagenes">
                <img src="../media/2.png"/ class="imagenes">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedor-imagenes">
                <img src="../media/room.jpg"/ class="imagenes">
                <img src="../media/skull.jpg"/ class="imagenes">
            </div>
            <div class="contenedor-imagenes">
                <img src="../media/3.jpg"/ class="imagenes">
                <img src="../media/4.png"/ class="imagenes">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="footer"></section>
```

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#main-content{ min-height: 100vh; margin:0; flex:1;  background: black;}

#navbar{ min-height:50px; z-index: 1;background:red;top: 0;left:0;width: 100%;}

#main-content{ display:flex; flex-direction:column; }

#footer{ min-height:50px;background: red;bottom: 0;left:0; width: 100%;}

.padre{
  background: red;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.contenedor-imagenes{
  display:flex;
  background: lightblue;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
img{
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

Images used

`https://res.cloudinary.com/demonjl/image/upload/v1677406549/Stack%20Overflow/2_g75230.png`

`https://res.cloudinary.com/demonjl/image/upload/v1677406547/Stack%20Overflow/4_bgqwvo.png`

`https://res.cloudinary.com/demonjl/image/upload/v1677406542/Stack%20Overflow/room_m3gvoh.jpg`

`https://res.cloudinary.com/demonjl/image/upload/v1677406541/Stack%20Overflow/skull_qtv0bs.jpg`

`https://res.cloudinary.com/demonjl/image/upload/v1677406541/Stack%20Overflow/3_hveyv2.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want right? if didn't get your answer please let me know.

Click on full page result to see the output correctly.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background:red;
}

.padre{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
    gap:4px;
}


img {
  max-height: 300px;
}

.first,.second,.third{
  display:flex;
justify-content:center;
  gap:4px;
}
.second_img{
  max-height:312px;
}
.third img{
  max-height:197.5px;
}
```

```html
<section id="navbar"></section>
<section id="main-content">
  <div class="padre">
    <div class="first">
      <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demonjl/image/upload/v1677406541/Stack%20Overflow/3_hveyv2.jpg" / class="imagenes">
      <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demonjl/image/upload/v1677406549/Stack%20Overflow/2_g75230.png

" / class="imagenes">
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demonjl/image/upload/v1677406542/Stack%20Overflow/room_m3gvoh.jpg

" / class="second_img">
      <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demonjl/image/upload/v1677406541/Stack%20Overflow/skull_qtv0bs.jpg

" / class="second_img">
    </div>
    <div class="third">
      <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demonjl/image/upload/v1677406541/Stack%20Overflow/3_hveyv2.jpg" / class="imagenes">
      <img src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demonjl/image/upload/v1677406547/Stack%20Overflow/4_bgqwvo.png

" / class="imagenes">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section id="footer"></section>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the answer! Now I am going to edit the post to add the new update with a separate file with your proposal so that I can later adapt it to main.

Since it turns out that it is going well but something is missing!

Comment: what is missing?

Comment: In the post there is an update section.
Inside this there are two photos, the first my case, and second as it should be

Comment: That's the idea, the only problem I see is when you want to load different images, they wouldn't adapt as is, because what you did is individually right? How would we calculate between the images that are inside a block/div. Thank you very much!